# How to block a user if a value selected from the database is 1?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have the following function that checks for a user login. At it's current state it checks either the username or email and the password ( hash ) and if the result match the ones in the db it returns some values ( please make abstraction of the other variables or functions that have no sense in there if you cannot see them ):

```
// Start Checking The Login Credentials
public function checkUserLogin($username, $password) {
    $password = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $this->salt($password));
    if(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $username)){
        $identifier = 'user_email';
    } else {
        $identifier = 'user_username';
    }
    $sql      = 'SELECT user_username,user_level FROM users WHERE '.$identifier.' = ? AND user_password = ?';
    // Check Login Attempts
    if (isset($_SESSION['attempts']) && $_SESSION['attempts'] >= NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS) {
        $lockdown            = true;
        $message['lockdown'] = true;
        $message['message']  = SYSTEM_LOCKDOWN_MESSAGE;
        return json_encode($message);
    } else {
        if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($username, $level);
            if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt->close();
                $_SESSION['member_logged_in'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username']         = $username;
                $_SESSION['level']            = $level;
                $_SESSION['attempts']         = 0;
                $ip = $this->getIP();
                $sql      = "UPDATE users SET user_last_login_date = NOW(), user_last_login_ip = '$ip' WHERE user_username = '$username'";
                if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                } else {
                    $error              = true;
                    $message['error']   = true;
                    $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
                    return json_encode($message);
                }
                $message['level']             = $level;
                if( $level = 0 ) {
                    $_SESSION['standard'] = true;   
                } elseif( $level = 1 ) {
                    $_SESSION['special'] = true;
                } elseif( $level = 2 ) {
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
                }
                $error                        = false;
                $message['error']             = false;
                $message['message']           = SUCCESFUL_LOGIN_MESSAGE;
                return json_encode($message);
            } else {
                @$_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['attempts'] + 1;
                $error              = true;
                $message['error']   = true;
                $message['message'] = FAILED_LOGIN_MESSAGE;
                return json_encode($message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is before returning the values if the credentials are found in the db and match, check for another value in the db called `user_disabled` which can be either `0` or `1` and if the `1` value is found return another message, something like `This account has been disabled` and if `0` is found, continue with the rest of the code as it was before ( a successful login ).

I have the following code which does approximately what I need, but when I tried to place inside this public function it doesn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_disabled FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'";
if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($disabled);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    if($disabled = 0){

        /* Here is what should happen if the user is not blocked | The code after "$stmt->fetch()" */

    } else {
        @$_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['attempts'] + 1;
        $error              = true;
        $message['error']   = true;
        $message['message'] = 'ceva';
        return json_encode($message);
    }
} else {
    $error              = true;
    $message['error']   = true;
    $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
    return json_encode($message);
}
```

Could someone help me out with this because I cannot figure out how to do it right ?

Comment: `if ($disabled == 0)`? You may need an extra equals sign

Comment: It's hard to say what your problem is because there is so much going on in the example. Perhaps if you could create a short, self-contained example displaying the problem it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: It is the `==`. Place your answer if you want so I can accept it.

Comment: Tips: bettr to use `if( 0 == $disabled )`

Comment: @diEcho - Could you tell me why is that ?

Comment: @Roland I assume he is referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138719/whats-the-reasoning-behind-putting-constants-in-if-statements-first

Comment: it's one of defensive programming techniques. To protect yourself from yourself.

Comment: This is a good point, thanks. What about js, should I apply the same technique ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
if($disabled = 0){
```

should read

```
if($disabled == 0){
```